# how to use single node js api for mobile app(android/ios) and web(template engine) both?

Tags: android, ios, node.js, rest, web

One API For both WEB & Mobile App

WEB: template engine like (hbs,ejs etc)

Mobile App: (Android / IOS)

Eg:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Hey', message: 'Hello there!' })
})
```

From above example i can get html response not json for mobile app..

Comment: After research,If you want to serve rendered page to web and plain json response to mobile requests you need to add some identifier to path.

Just make sure you add an extra header to your request from mobile ( isMobile : true ) and then read it in the request mapping function

And return res.json() if header is their or return res.rendor()

Comment: You have only two choices, don't you? As it's mentioned in dupe question, a more straightforward way is to use content negotiation, i.e. `req.format`. You can also use http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.accepts if you want to make decisions by yourself. I.e. res.render for `Accepts: text/html` header and res.json for `Accepts: application/json`. This is how APIs are usually built. Another way is to just have two different entry points for static pages and REST API. Not every API end point has respective HTML page, and vice versa.